# I have two matching tables, only one has changed data. How to prioritize the latter over the first in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

We have two tables, for example:

Houses

- id
- name
- address
- occupants

Customer_houses

- id
- customer_id
- name
- address
- occupants

Now, what we want to enable is, to allow customers to edit their house, this will make a copy of the 'houses' table to the 'customer_houses' table.

When we retrieve the data, we want to show the customer_houses data instead of the houses_data *if the first is available*.
How can we do this in Laravel Eloquent?
What is the best approach, keeping speed and complexity in mind?

I know we could do a select on customer_houses, and if we find a record, use that, and if not run another select. But that doesn't look very efficient to me.

Comment: You don't seem to have a way of identifying house in customer or if you have multiple customers/houses (ie multiple edits) which to select.

Comment: I get the feeling there may have been a bad decision made at database design time here

Comment: The decision hasn't yet been made. I am searching for the best solution.

Comment: Start by revisiting your design and or naming conventions bearing in mind what you want out of it.

Comment: We have a foundation of data (the original data), which a customer may edit to his liking. When customer retrieves the data, the data that is attached to the customer account should come in first (and only if found). If there is no data for the customer found, then load the original one.

Comment: As `customer_houses` has no link to `houses` How will you know other than comparing `name,address,occupation` all of which are text, and editable by the user, therefore most unlikely to ever match once you allow any editing. I think you need to have a rethink on this db design based on what you want to be able to do with this data. You have committed the ultimate sin in DB design, that of placing the same data in more than one place

Comment: I think of adding 'ref_id' into 'customer_houses' so we can check the ID in 'customer_houses' and if present load that. If not present, load the original.